# PHP/HTML - How to put columns from the same "$row" of different conditions side by side?

Tags: php, html

I have php code using "foreach" loop with "if" condition and Data from SQL. I want to separate the results into two different columns based on their conditions. This is the code:

```
foreach($data as $row) {

if($row['Code'] == 235 && $row['PR'] == 592735 && $row['Status'] == "todo" ) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Column'] . "</td>";
    
    }
if($row['Code'] == 235 && $row['PR'] == 592705 && $row['Status'] == "todo") {
    echo "<td>" . $row['Column'] . "</td>";

}
echo "</tr>";

}
```

My problem is now, the rows are all printed in one column like a list, like this:

| Column |
| --- |
| row (condition1) |
| row (condition1) |
| row (condition2) |
| row (condition2) |

I wanted to separate both conditions into two columns:

| Condition1 | Condition2 |
| --- | --- |
| row | row |
| row | row |

I tried playing with html but it does not work. Is there any way to achieve this using php? By the way, I am a PHP-Beginner.

Comment: Seems like you would need to reformat your results before printing them. Are there always going to be equal number of elements for each column?

Comment: Put your `echo '<tr>'` *outside* of the first condition, as in before it.

Comment: @El_Vanja no the number of elements won't always be the same

Comment: @GetSet i've tried it but it does not work either.

Comment: In that case, Nathanael's answer seems optimal.

Comment: Ok. Its good practice to update your question with any help you received, so that your code being inspected is up-to-date, for future questions on debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split your array into two arrays and then generate the html with the resulting arrays

```
$condition1 = $condition2 = [];
foreach($data as $row) {
    if($row['Code'] == 235 && $row['PR'] == 592735 && $row['Status'] == "todo" ) {
        $condition1[] =  $row['Column'];
    }
    if($row['Code'] == 235 && $row['PR'] == 592705 && $row['Status'] == "todo") {
        $condition2[] = $row['Column'];
    }
}

for($k=0; $k < max(count($condition1),count($condition2));$k++) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.($condition1[$k] ?? '').'</td><td>'. ($condition2[$k] ?? '').'</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
If first condition fill first column with the result and second empty else fill first column empty and second with data

```
foreach($data as $row) {

echo "<tr>";
if($row['Code'] == 235 && $row['PR'] == 592735 && $row['Status'] == "todo" ) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['Column'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
}
if($row['Code'] == 235 && $row['PR'] == 592705 && $row['Status'] == "todo") {
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Column'] . "</td>";

}
echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: The problem is the "<tr>" creates a row inside a condition. Which should not be the case, This is evident by the closing "</tr>" outside of a condition.

Comment: This works but not like what I have in mind. The cells from column 1 and 2 are not inline, thus it gives empty cells.